# Cast Component[] -> JButton

Tags: java, swing

I'm programming Java with NetBeans. I have a strange problem. In a class Mouse Listener, I do getComponents of a panel, and it returns a array of components that I put(?) in one array JButton (whit cast) so..

```
JButton[] b= (JButton[])Main.p1.getComponents();
```

IDE doesn't show an error.
I do, for example:

```
b[0].setBackground(Color.yellow);
```

and in output I see an error.

But if I do

```
JButton b= (JButton) Main.p1.getComponents()[0];

b.setBackground(...);
```

And all works but I don't understand why. Can somebody explain please?

2015-01-18

Thank to all for the answer. 
I want take Components of a Panel, not only for change background's color, but also for the Ordinates; I need all Buttons in a array to compare all at the same time .. Why I cant convert 'Components' in 'Buttons'? Panel has a pointer to Buttons in Ram Memory.. 
Patryk Dobrowolski thank's you, i try this:  (i use class Button extends JButton)

`Button[] button = new Button[Main.p1.getComponents().length];
   for (int i = 0; i < Main.p1.getComponents().length; i++) {
   button[i] = (Button) Main.p1.getComponents()[i];` 
}

but in output I see this error:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JLabel cannot be cast to Button
```

why JLabel?

Hovercraft Full Of Eels, thank's you for your answer, I could create an array and insert the pointer of all Button into it. But I said: JPannel has a Array where insert pointer.. I can use it. Why not?
Thank's you very much!

Alessandro Amedei

Comment: Please [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: More code would be helpful, and the actual error message would be helpful too. I worry about your use of `getComponents()` and wonder if your program design could be improved. Also, hopefully you're not adding MouseListeners to your JButtons.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are lying to the compiler. By stating

```
JButton[] b= (JButton[])Main.p1.getComponents();
```

you are telling the compiler that you know that this is an array of `JButton`s, when in fact it really is an array of `Component`s. Therefore you get no compile-time errors, but you do get one at runtime.

In the other case it works, since then you are telling the compiler that the `Component` you want to work with is a `JButton`, which is true.

Comment: @ original poster (Alessandro Amedei): this answer is the correct one (one plus to it), but again I re-iterate my concern that you're using the component structure of your program's GUI "view" code as a key part of the structure of your program's logic, the "model" part, and this is a dangerous thing to do for many reasons. I am sure that there is a much better object-oriented way of tying your view to your model.

Answer (score 2):

It's because array of JComponent is not the same as array of JButton. You need to cast one by one in the loop if you want to finally get array of buttons:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[components.length];
for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
   buttons[i] = (JButton) components[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am concerned that you are trying to extract your selected JButton by iterating through an array of components and thereby basing your program logic on the GUI component structure, which is a very fragile way to do things. If you change components around, or later decide to nest a container that holds your JButtons into another container (i.e., into another JPanel), you would have to take care to update this listener and all similar listeners, again making your code quite fragile.

Rather than do this, a better solution might be to add a listener to the individual components that need them. For instance, if you want to change the background of a JButton to yellow if a mouse is hovering over it, consider adding a ChangeListener to each JButton, extracting the involved button via the ChangeEvent's `getSource()` method and then testing the button's model to see if it is in a roll-over state. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SetButtonBackground extends JPanel {

   public static final Color ROLLOVER_COLOR = Color.yellow;

   public SetButtonBackground() {
      int rows = 5;
      int cols = rows;
      setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 5, 5));

      ButtonChangeListener btnChngListener = new ButtonChangeListener();
      for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
         String text = "Button " + (i + 1);
         JButton button = new JButton(text);
         button.addChangeListener(btnChngListener);
         add(button);
      }
   }

   private class ButtonChangeListener implements ChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
         ButtonModel model = btn.getModel();
         if (model.isRollover()) {
            if (!btn.getBackground().equals(ROLLOVER_COLOR)) {
               btn.setBackground(ROLLOVER_COLOR);
            }
         } else if (btn.getBackground().equals(ROLLOVER_COLOR)) {
            btn.setBackground(null); // change back to default state
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SetButtonBackground mainPanel = new SetButtonBackground();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Set Button Background");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```